# fully applying functions in Scala, shorthand notation impossible?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, lambda

Is there a way to declare a fully-applied function without a full new lambda?

```
scala> val F = (x: Int) => math.pow(x,2)
F: Int => Double = <function1>
scala> val G = F(3)
G: Double = 9.0
```

How can I declare it such that G is an:

```
() => Double = <function0>
```

Without doing this:

```
scala> val G = () => F(3)
G: () => Double = <function0>
```

?  The _ notation doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
scala> val G = F(3) _
<console>:8: error: _ must follow method; cannot follow Double
       val G = F(3) _
```

Comment: what about `def`? (`def G(): Double = F(3)`) - aside from this if you don't have any sideeffects this will be just the same as a constant - so why use a function at all? - PS: where is the connection to "partially-applied-type"?

Comment: Yes, if there are no side-effects, it is the same, but if not, there is.  If I were only binding one argument of an two-argument (arity-2 I believe?) function, it would be called a partially-applied function, would it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way. The shortest form is what you came up with, i.e., `() => F(3)`.

Comment: How about: `_ => F(3)`

Comment: @drsquidop That creates a one-argument function of type `Unit => Double` (and even then, only if there is an appropriate expected type, otherwise it doesn't compile), which is not the same as a zero-argument function of type `() => Double` that is asked by the OP.